# .htaccess help - Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I currently have an `.htaccess` file to rewrite `index.php` out of all of the base URL's, example `example.com/index.php/home -> example.com/home`

The `.htacces` file is as follows in the root of my `public_html` folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|adminer|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

As far as I know, this rewrites any `/URL` that isn't `images, css, resources, etc..` to point toward `index.php`.

I am now trying to add to my `.htaccess` a rule to rewrite `example.com/forums -> fourms.example.com`.

With the current rules in place, I receive a `500 - Internal Server Error` when I try to visit `forums.example.com`. I have also tried the following to no avail:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|adminer|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/forums(.*)
RewriteRule ^forums(.*)$ http://forums.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

How do I change these rules to allow the redirection of `index.php` and rewrite `example.com/fourms` to `fourms.example.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And for the second time today, I have found the answer moments after posting a question:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|resources|forums|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/forums(.*)
RewriteRule ^forums(.*)$ http://forums.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

I had to exclude `/forums` from the first rewrite, and add in the second rewrite.